# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-2+3-4+\dots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+ \sqrt{4n^2-1}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-2+3-4+\dots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+ \sqrt{4n^2-1}}$ seems to tend towards -$\frac{1}{3}$, and is likely to converge, but I am unsure of how to proceed. It seems likely to rationalise the denominator, but I have no idea how to proceed from there. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-\sum_{r=1}^n\{2r-(2r-1)\}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{4n^2-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{n^2}}+\sqrt{4-\dfrac1{n^2}}}=?$$

Comment: To show the first equality, do we first need to show the series is absolutely convergent? Apart from that, would it be right to say that the sequence simplify to -$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n^2}}}$, and hence the limit is -$\frac{1}{6}?$

Comment: @David, The simplification of numerator does not require convergence validation. Couldn't make out the $$1+\dfrac1n$$ part

Comment: Am I right in doing this simplification? $−\sum^n_{r=1}{2r−(2r−1)} = -\sum^n_{r=1}(1) = \sum^n_{r=1}(-1) = -\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: @David, $$\sum_{r=1}^n(-1)=n(-1)$$

Comment: Ahhh right. Thank you!